What did Mr Paradox want from Wade Wilson?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), Wade Wilson is kidnapped from his home timeline by “Paradox,” a low level executive working for the TVA, from whom he learns that the death of his timeline’s Wolverine means the end of the entire timeline and the death of his friends.
Wade responds by reclaiming his “Deadpool” persona, stealing a time controller, and recruiting a living Wolverine from another timeline to replace the one who had died in his own. This was not what Paradox had intended, and the two are soon shunted onto the quest that forms the majority of the movie’s plot.
What did Paradox want? Why did he pick Wade from his dying timeline? What could Wade have done for him that he couldn’t have done himself or with his existing staff?

I think there was some comment about Wade being chosen by the higher-ups in the TVA for "some great purpose" and Paradox was just using someone already chosen to subvert what they wanted. In fact, it seems to me that Wade was just a distraction from what Paradox was actually trying to do.

The TVA recruited Deadpool to potentially become an Avenger and save the Sacred Timeline from a future threat.
Paradox explains the TVA's motivations to Deadpool:

You're special. In fact, you've been chosen for a higher purpose, a purpose unclear even to me. But, one could save the entire Sacred Timeline from a possibly grisly fate sometime in the future, which may very well need to be avenged…


You can be a hero among heroes. We've been surveilling you for quite a while.


I brought you here to offer you an opportunity. The opportunity you sought years ago. […] I'm about to give you the thing you've always wanted.

This suggests that the TVA sees something unique in Deadpool. The TVA believes Wade has the potential to join the Avengers and play a crucial role in protecting the Sacred Timeline from an unspecified future danger. The exact nature of this role seems unclear even to Paradox, hinting that this plan likely originated from higher-ranking TVA members.

Though, one must keep in mind that after the events of Loki season-2, there is no sacred timeline!
